# Sidekiq worker using a a "custom" queue name gets assigned to "default" queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, queue, sidekiq

```
Rails 3.2.9
Ruby 1.9.3dev (2011-09-23 revision 33323) [i686-linux]
sidekiq  2.10.1
```

If I define a worker like below with a custom queue name

```
  class BulkEmailWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    # https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options
    sidekiq_options(queue: :bulk_mails, backtrace: true)

    # https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices
    # Section: Make your jobs small and simple
    def perform
      # https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-Extensions
      scheduled_mails = MailTemplate.with_schedule
      scheduled_mails.each do |mail_template|
        BulkMailer.delay.general_mail(mail_template.id)
      end
    end
  end
```

and I invoke the worker like this:

```
  BulkEmailWorker.perform_async
```

it doesn't work (in other words doesn't send email).

Inspecting the data in redis I found following:

```
  redis 127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
  1) "myapp:stat:processed:2013-04-24"
  2) "myapp:queue:default"
  3) "myapp:stat:processed"
  4) "myapp:queues"

  redis 127.0.0.1:6379> lrange myapp:queue:default -100 100

   1) "{\"retry\":true,\"queue\":\"default\",\"timeout\":30,\"class\":\"Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer\",\"args\":[\"---\\n- !ruby/class 'BulkMailer'\\n- :general_mail\\n- - 1\\n\"],\"jid\":\"e46693944febf7ae26ec67a0\"}"
```

redis 127.0.0.1:6379>

**As can be seen above the worker is assigned to queue "default" and I guess due to this the worker is unable to process.**

I started sidekiq using following command for above scenario:

```
  bundle exec sidekiq -e dev_mysql -C config/sidekiq.yml -q bulk_mails
```

However when I remove from my worker following

```
    sidekiq_options(queue: :bulk_mails, backtrace: true)
```

and start sidekiq using following command:

```
  bundle exec sidekiq -e dev_mysql -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

it works (in other words it sends email successfully).

*/config/sidekiq.yml*

```
# https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Logging
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260634/sidekiq-configuration-for-multiple-environments
---
  :verbose: true
  :pidfile: ./tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
  :logfile: ./log/sidekiq.log
  :concurrency:  25
```

I have just started using Sidekiq and am novice to it.So please bear with me if I there is some concept which I misunderstood or unaware about.

I need to get rid of the mentioned problem so that my worker gets assigned to the desired queue and also processed successfully.

Thanks,
Jignesh

Answer (score 19):

In addition, note that you can push a job on the queue you want by using `Sidekiq::Client.push` instead of `perform_async`:

```rb
Sidekiq::Client.push({
  'class' => BulkEmailWorker,
  'queue' => 'bulk_mails',
  'args'  => [ 1, 2 ]
})
```

Note that the keys (`class`, `queue`, `args`) **must** be strings, not symbols, or you will get the `ArgumentError: Message must include a class and set of arguments`.

This is especially useful when you need to push a job on a queue with a variable name (bulk_mails.1, bulk_mails.2, etc.), so you can easily **control concurrency** by allowing only one job at a time on some queues, thanks to [sidekiq-limit_fetch](https://github.com/brainopia/sidekiq-limit_fetch).

Comment: No spaces after ( ) and [ ] is considered a good code style guideline. so `[ 1, 2 ]` should be `[1, 2]`. https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-spaces-braces

Answer (score 8):

You can add the queue names and weights in the sidekiq.yml config file:

```
:queues:
- [bulk_mails, 7]
- [default, 5]
```

Start sidekiq with the `-C config/sidekiq.yml` option. Now you can refer to the queue name in your worker:

```
sidekiq_options :queue => :bulk_mails
```

Comment: Thanks zwippie for your response.I just received a comment from @mperham at https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/872.